# SQL Server : conditional aggregate ;

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  Year       Value
  -----------------
  2013      -0.0016
  2014      -0.0001
  2015       0.0025
  2016      -0.0003
  2017       0.0023
  2018       0.0002
```

And I need to perform a conditional aggregate that results in a new column. The conditions are as follows:

If the value is negative then the aggregation starts and doesn't stop until the value is positive.  Then nothing until the value is negative again... The result will look like this:

```
  Year       Value        AggCol
  2013      -0.0016      -0.0016
  2014      -0.0001      -0.0017
  2015       0.0025       0.0008
  2016      -0.0003      -0.0003
  2017       0.0023       0.002
  2018       0.0002       0.0002
```

This udf is as close as I have gotten:

```
create function dbo.fn(@cYear numeric, @rate float)
returns float
as 
begin
    declare @pYear numeric
    declare @return float

    set @pYear = @cYear - 1

    set @return = (select 
                        case 
                            when Value < 0 and @rate > 0  then null 
                            when Value < 0 then Value + @rate
                            else @rate 
                        end 
                   from Table1 
                   where [year] = @pYear)

    return @return
end
```

I am ok with an answer in c# if that would be easier but prefer SQL.  The issue with the function I made is I need to be able to grab the results from the previous row to add to value when the value is positive.

I was up all night on here searching for clues and no joy...

EDIT: So think of these as CPI values for the year to be applied to your cellphone bill by your carrier...  They are only going to increase your bill by the CPI, and never decrease it (if CPI is negative)... but they will offset the previous years negative CPI by the current years CPI if the Current year CPI is positive (or the sum results in a positive)...

That may or may not help but that is the situation lol.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You can do this using a query in SQL Server, but it requires recursive CTEs.

Comment: 2012 and I'm ok with CTE's... have dbo access, so can do anything needed.

Comment: "until the value is positive", do you mean the value in the table or the accumulated sum?

Comment: Until the value from the table is positive.

Comment: although i think the outer apply might perform better in this case, here's a recursive cte for reference.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca764/1

Comment: nevermind.. i see "Until the value from the table is positive".. well that would have made things a lot easier :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( [Year] INT, Value MONEY )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 2013, -0.0016 ),
        ( 2014, -0.0001 ),
        ( 2015, 0.0025 ),
        ( 2016, -0.0003 ),
        ( 2017, 0.0023 ),
        ( 2018, 0.0002 )

SELECT  t1.Year ,
        t1.Value ,
        oa.AggCol
FROM    @t t1
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    SUM(Value) AS AggCol
                      FROM      @t t2
                      WHERE     Year <= t1.Year
                                AND Year > ( SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Year), 0)
                                             FROM   @t
                                             WHERE  Year < t1.Year AND Value > 0)
                    ) oa
```

Output:

```
Year    Value    AggCol
2013    -0.0016  -0.0016
2014    -0.0001  -0.0017
2015    0.0025   0.0008
2016    -0.0003  -0.0003
2017    0.0023   0.002
2018    0.0002   0.0002
```

That means: for each row give me a sum of values less or equal than current row and greater than maximal row with positive value that appears before current row, or starting from 0 if no such found.

Comment: You sir are a freak of nature!  I mean that in the most complimentary way possible as I am blown away by the speed you answered this!  Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @user3486773, thank you too for interesting question.

Comment: This is a great attempt and works with the test data provided but it breaks down when it will take multiple positive Values to make the running sum a positive number.  e.g. change 2014 to .0001 and year 2015 will have the wrong value present.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using window functions:

```sql
;WITH PrevValues AS (
   SELECT Year, Value,
          LAG(Value) OVER (ORDER BY Year) AS prevValue
   FROM Table1
), Flags AS (
  SELECT Year, Value,
         CASE 
            WHEN Value < 0 AND prevValue > 0 THEN 2  -- next slice
            WHEN Value < 0 OR prevValue < 0  THEN 1  -- same slice
            WHEN Value > 0 AND prevValue > 0 THEN -1 -- not in a slice
         END AS flag
  FROM PrevValues
), Islands AS (
  SELECT Year, Value,    
       CASE 
          WHEN flag = -1 THEN -1   
          ELSE SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY Year)      
               -
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year) 
       END AS grp
  FROM Flags
)
SELECT Year, Value,
       CASE 
          WHEN grp = -1 THEN Value
          ELSE SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY Year) 
       END AS AggCol
FROM Islands
ORDER BY Year
```

The idea is to identify islands of rows over which the running sum is applied.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ac1e/1)

Comment: This is a great attempt and works with the test data provided but it breaks down when it will take multiple positive Values to make the running sum a positive number.  e.g. change 2014 to .0001 and year 2015 will have the wrong value present.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( [Year] INT, Value MONEY )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES (2013,-0.0016),(2014,0.0001),(2015,0.0025),(2016,-0.0003),(2017,0.0023),(2018,0.0002)

;WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year) as RowNum
    FROM
       @t
)
, cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       Year
       ,Value
       ,Value as AggCol
       ,RowNum
    FROM
       cteRowNum
    WHERe
       RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       c.Year
       ,c.Value
       ,CASE
          WHEN AggCol >= 0 THEN c.Value
          ELSE AggCol + c.Value
       END
       ,c.RowNum
    FROM
       cteRecursive r
       INNER JOIN cteRowNum c
       ON r.RowNum + 1 = c.RowNum
)

SELECT Year, Value, AggCol
FROM
    cteRecursive
```

**NOTE THIS IS A DIFFERENT DATA SET THAN WHAT YOU PROVIDED! here are the results**

```
Year    Value        AggCol
2013    -0.0016     -0.0016
2014     0.0001     -0.0015
2015     0.0025      0.001
2016    -0.0003     -0.0003
2017     0.0023      0.002
2018     0.0002      0.0002
```

The problem with your original test data is that it did not account for the situation where it would take multiple sequential positive records to make the running sum positive.  **Subsequently BOTH other answers at the time I am posting my answer are wrong**. So I changed only the 2014 record to positive .0001 and you can see how this solution works and the others do not.

There are probably ways of doing this with window functions but the recursive cte is pretty straight forward so I went that route:

- First build a row_number on the dataset to use in the joins to account for situation if a YEAR is missing in your dataset or something.
- Next build the recursive cte and step 1 row at a time using the row number and determine if the aggregate value needs to be reset or added to based on whether the previous rows value is positive or negative.

Here are the results of Giorgos & Giorgi's answers if you make the change to the test data:

```
Year    Value        AggCol
2013    -0.0016     -0.0016
2014     0.0001     -0.0015
2015     0.0025      0.0025
2016    -0.0003     -0.0003
2017     0.0023      0.002
2018     0.0002      0.0002
```

You can see the problem with the AggCol for Year 2015 is wrong

Please note I think there answers are great attempts and show some real skill/code when it comes to gaps/islands. I am not trying to attack simply enhance the quality of the post.